# Prop is wrong in components method

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I've ran in to a very weird thing.
I render a component 2 times and pass the props; title and container.

Like this :

```html
<FileReader
    @load="load"
    title="Ladda upp PI loggfil"
    container="piLog"
/>
<FileReader
    @load="load"
    title="Ladda upp AI loggfil"
    container="aiLog"
/>
```

In the component I have a method called `submitFile` which reads a file and **emits** it with the *content* aswell as the *container prop* the content is suppose to end up in.

```js
submitFile(e) {
      const file = e.target.files[0];
      const reader = new FileReader();

      reader.onload = (e) =>
        this.$emit("load", {
          content: e.target.result,
          container: this.$props.container,
        });
      reader.readAsText(file);
    }
```

The problem is that `this.$props.container` returns the wrong prop which is very weird as if I render the prop its **correct**. I can also console.log the **prop** on the `mounted()` event and the prop is correct. But in the function its wrong. It's always the component renderded first. By that I mean, if the first component has the **container** prop as "blabla". The second components **prop** will be correct in the render but wrong when used in the `submitFile` function.

I even tried creating a new variable through:

`data() {return {test: this.$props.container}}`
and then using this.test insted of this.$props.container in the `submitFile` function but its still wrong.

I also tried passing the prop as a prop when I call the function.

This is the FileReader component:

```html
<template>
  <div class="file__container">
    <label for="file-upload" class="custom-file-upload">
      {{ title }}
    </label>
    <input id="file-upload" type="file" @change="submitFile" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  mounted() {
    console.log(this.$props.container); // debug
  },

  methods: {
    submitFile(ev) {
      const file = ev.target.files[0];
      const reader = new FileReader();

      reader.onload = (e) =>
        this.$emit("load", {
          content: e.target.result,
          container: this.container,
        });
      reader.readAsText(file);
    },
  },

  props: ["title", "container"],
};
</script>
```

This is where I initiate the component.

```html
<div class="user__interaction">
      <h2>Log Viewer</h2>
      <div class="flex-row">
        <FileReader
          @load="load"
          title="Ladda upp PI loggfil"
          container="piLog"
        />
        <FileReader
          @load="load"
          title="Ladda upp AI loggfil"
          container="aiLog"
        />
      </div>
      <IDviewer title="PI Signaler hittade:" :container="this.piLog" />
      <IDviewer title="AI Signaler hittade:" :container="this.aiLog" />
 </div>
```

Comment: At least:
1. You have two `e` params 
2. `this.$props.container` better be simply `this.container`

Comment: doesnt change anything ): I get the same result

Comment: I didn't propose a solution, just minor issues. Please add a code/template where you instantiate  both components.

Comment: I edited now and added more code.

Comment: Why does the FileReader component need the `container` prop? It doesn't use it at all except for emitting it with the `load` event. The parent already knows what the container is.

Comment: Two things: You have `:container="this.piLog"` in your template but it should be just `:container="piLog"`. So if `piLog` is a property then shouldn't you also bind it to the FileReader prop like `:container="piLog"`?

Comment: I use `:container="this.piLog"` on the IDviewer as I need the `this.piLog` object but in the filereader it justs **states** where this read file will end up. In my `load()` function it retrives this **container** aswell as the **content** from the loaded file. From here it formats the content and creates a object `this[container] = {}`. In this object all the information from the log file uploaded gets formated correctly. So I can then use these objects in the template.